# jpa fetch many query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I do a custom query, user enter two id

```
platformsId=1 
typesId=1
```

Around 18 queries are done
My class

```
@Entity
public class Head {

    @Id
    private Integer id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "head")
    private List<PackageInstances> packageInstance;

    @ManyToOne 
    private Platforms platform;

    @ManyToOne
    private Types type;

     @ManyToOne
    private Owners Owner;

    @ManyToOne
    private Pack package;

}
```

Query I create in function of parameters value

```
@Override
public Page<Head> advancedSearch(HeadSearch search, Pageable page) {
    Specification<Head> specification = (Root<Head> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {
        Predicate p = cb.conjunction();

        if (search.getId() != null) {
            p.getExpressions().add(cb.equal(root.get("id"), search.getId()));
        }

        if (search.getOwnersId() != null) {
            Join<Head, Owners> owners = root.join("Owner");
            p.getExpressions().add(cb.equal(owners.get("id"), search.getOwnersId()));
        }

        if (search.getTypesId() != null) {
            Join<Head, Types> types = (Join) root.fetch("type");
            p.getExpressions().add(cb.equal(types.get("id"), search.getTypesId()));
        }

        if (search.getPlatformsId() != null) {

            Join<Head, Platforms> platform = (Join) root.fetch("platform");
            p.getExpressions().add(cb.equal(platform.get("id"), search.getPlatformsId()));
        }

        if (search.getPackagesId() != null) {
            Join<Head, Pack> packages = root.join("package");
            p.getExpressions().add(cb.equal(packages.get("id"), search.getPackagesId()));
        }
        return p;
    };

    return this.findAll(specification, page);
    }
```

Sure paging will do some query, but surely not causing all query who are done.
Fetch don't seem to change anything.

I tried to add JoinColumn, but get same issue.

Is there a way to optimize that, any way to avoid so many query?

Comment: When you say "Fetch don't seem to change anything" what did you try? Because @ManyToOne default fetch strategy is EAGER.

Comment: if you check the query i done, i use fetch command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [JPA 2.1 specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf) `@ManyToOne` relationship have a default fetch strategy to `FetchType.Eager` and your entity class have 4 of that kind with that strategy.

When you are building the criteria you use `fetch` on the `Types` and `Platforms` (and only if there is data to do that) and `join` on the 2 others. So when the entities are retrieve with the request, hibernate will perform the eagerly fetch on every unresolved `@ManyToOne` relation, which is in your case depending on the user's input is between 2 and 4 per `Head`.

To reduce the number or request you should either set the FetchStrategy to lazy on the relation:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

or refactor your code to force the fetch everything with the initial query.

Comment: do i need to join also PackageInstances?

Comment: It depends on the result you expect from your query, what entities must be fetched or not for your needs.